# safari 6 caching POST requests

Tags: ajax, caching, post, ios6, safari6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS6 Safari Caching $.ajax Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/ios6-safari-caching-ajax-results)

Issue pointed out here:
[Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/ios6-safari-caching-ajax-results)

my Q's are:

1. Is there a pointer to some apple document explaining the nature of
   this change? do they consider this to be a bug (to be fixed when?)
   or a feature?
2. What can be done for the meanwhile other then adding a
   cache buster to all the POST requests made by the client
   application/site?
3. Is there maybe a header that can be returned from the server to prohibit this behavior of the safari 6 browser?