# iOS 6 Mobile Safari Session Variables not retained when set via AJAX

Tags: ajax, mobile-safari, session-variables, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results)

I have been having a problem with session variables set via AJAX in mobile Safari iOS 6. I included a sample that will set a session variable, redirect to another page, abandon the session and start over.  This works fine the first 2 times.  On the third time through the process, the session variables get lost. The problem only happens in iOS 6 safari.  It works in all other browsers I have tried.

The sample consists of 3 pages. Page1 sets the session variable and redirects to Page 2.  Page 2 displays the session variable.  Page 3 abandons the session variable.

Page 1 HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Page1.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div onclick="setSessionVariable()">Set session variable and redirect to page 2</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 1 Javascript:

```
function setSessionVariable() {
    PageMethods.SetSessionVariable(displaySetSessionVariable);
}

function displaySetSessionVariable(bReturn) {
    window.location = "Page2.aspx";
}
```

Page 1 Code:

```
using System.Web.Services;

namespace SafariSessionProblem {
    public partial class Page1 : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static Boolean SetSessionVariable() {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["TestVariable"] = 1;
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Page 2 HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br /><br />
        <div onclick="window.location = 'Page3.aspx'">Redirect to page 3 and abondon session</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2 Code:

```
namespace SafariSessionProblem {
    public partial class Page2 : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            lbl.Text = Session["TestVariable"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Page 3 HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div onclick="window.location = 'Page1.aspx'">Start over</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 3 Code:

```
namespace SafariSessionProblem {
    public partial class Page3 : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Session.Abandon();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am running into similar issue with IOS6 session variables..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figure out the issue its because in IOS6 Safari cached ajax requests and responses, so instead on sending request to server it uses cached requests. in order to over come this just add timestamp into your Ajax requests, it will work fine. i have placed code that I have used update your code with the help of this. hope will help you.

this is new variable to overcome this issue parameters.timeStamp = new Date().getTime();

```
    parameters.qString = location.hash;
parameters.timeStamp = new Date().getTime();//this new line for safari issue

application.ajax({
    url: application.ajaxUrl + "ajax",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $.extend({method:parameters.method}, parameters),
    success: function( response ){
        stop_spinner();
            })
        });
```

Thanks