# Safari Remote Debugging on Windows

Tags: windows, safari, ios6, remote-debugging

With the release of iOS 6, Apple implemented a feature called [remote debugging](http://html5-mobile.de/blog/ios6-remote-debugging-web-inspector?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+video-flash+%28www.video-flash.de%29)

A client is having problems with my webapp since installing the new iOS 6 and I can't figure out the issue.  It doesn't seem to be an issue with [caching of AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results), because the errors occur randomly and the problem is not (only) that results are still the same.

So it has to be a problem with parallel [AJAX-Calls](http://www.realsoftwareblog.com/2012/09/ios-6-mobile-safari-web-applications.html)

To identify the problem and efficiently fix it (instead stumbling in the dark) I need a debugger. I was happy to read about the remote debugging feature but I cannot get it to work.

---

## The Questions now are:

- Is it possible to use remote debugging in the Windows version of Safari?
- If so, how do I activate it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408110/debug-ipad-safari-with-a-pc/35714835

Comment: The answer in 2018: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786618

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How to debug Safari iOS when you're on Windows?

- Those nice Safari developer tools for iPhone require Safari 6, i.e. **they are NOT available on Windows.** *There are no plans for a Windows version of Safari 6 or, as Apple put it: "Safari 6 is available for Mountain Lion and Lion. Safari 5 continues to be available for Windows." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29#Safari_6)*
- If your local web server (e.g.: XAMPP) is properly configured, you *should* be able to visit it from your iPhone once it's connected to your computer. However, on Windows, this does not work either.

**Alternatives:**

- ***WebKit Debug Proxy*** is likely to offer similar functionality using Chrome in place of Safari one day: https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy* *"Windows support is planned but not implemented yet."*
- Use ***jsconsole*** for Remote Debugging: http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html Not safe AT ALL for production (read the warnings, don't use in prod) but very handy.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: jsconsole is no longer available

Comment: @StepanYakovenko Currently it is (9/10/19)

Comment: did you try to use it?

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a pretty easy way to debug a website in Safari on iOS using Firefox WebIDE on a Windows machine. I wrote an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35714835/306179 further describing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you're [BrowserSync](https://www.browsersync.io/) (which u should, btw), you can use it's remote debugging feature which is accessible from the UI. It should work with Safari mobile.

There's a topic about this already:
[How to do remote debugging with Browser-sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470601/how-to-do-remote-debugging-with-browser-sync)

This cool feature is powered by [Weinre](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/). Not the most pleasant debugger. But it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding on ios device is easy. but the problem is, that ios does not run inspector by default on any port by default.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I see currently is [Telerik](http://telerik.com) "AppBuilder". However it's very expensive...

Comment: I tried this and got hung up on provisioning. I'm not familiar with mobile development, especially apple, and I didn't have any of the credentials that it seemed like I needed to access the ipad from appbuilder, even though all I cared about was remotely debugging safari.