# Remote debugging javascript on iPad from a Windows machine possible?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari, remote-debugging

I have an iPad with iOS 6.1 connected to a windows 8 machine. I would like to be able to debug some javascript code running on the iPad.

The safari on iPad has a web inspect option that needs the iPad to be connected by wire to computer and then can be accessed in Safari for desktop's develop menu. I installed Safari 5 for Windows but don't see the iPad detected in the develop menu.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: See also [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/). It's not a javascript *debugger*, but it might still be useful.

Comment: It [doesn't work in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598415/safari-remote-debugging-on-windows); at least because it requires Safari 6.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox Tools Adaptor allows one to use Firefox DevTools for Safari on iOS.

https://github.com/mozilla/valence#debugging-safari-firefox-and-other-webviews-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

For remote debuggin I use [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/).

Weinre has almost everything you need, but lacks a JavaScript debugger.

It has a WebInspector for DOM manipulations, network traffic, timeline, resources and a console.

Checkout this project on GitHub: [weinre-remote-debug](https://github.com/elgervb/weinre-remote-debugging) to setup weinre locally.

Answer (score 0):

Another option described on [this page](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/) is **[jsconsole.com](http://jsconsole.com)**.  By appending a `<script>` tag to your page (or running a bookmarklet on your device) you get access to a JS console.

To start, go to jsconsole.com and run `:listen` in the prompt. This will give you a unique session ID and a script tag that you insert into your mobile web page.

[image]

Now, any console output that your mobile page generates will be streamed to the console open in your desktop web browser, including any errors!

[image]

It is certainly no replacement for a full web inspector, but it can get you out of trouble when you don’t have access to a Mac.

Source: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/