# Enable iPhone (with iOS7) debug console from Windows

Tags: ios, window

I'm trying to debug my website, but Apple are douches. What do I do to enable the debug console if I don't have a Mac?

I installed Safari and the latest iTunes, but my iPhone doesn't show up in Safari developer thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try option of using Telerik AppBuilder (Windows client) as a replacement on Windows for Safari debugger on Mac when remote debugging. There's a nice blog post about the steps to do it in link below. I'd rather not repost the info as there are also screenshots and it's a lot of text. But essentially, you install app, open it, connect device via USB, then you can find it in the app and open up the developer tools/debugger for it. For non-public websites, you'll have to open up port 80 with some firewall configs documented in the post.

http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/josh-eastburn/2014/03/04/ios-web-inspector-on-windows-with-telerik-appbuilder

The tool requires a license or you can use the trial, which becomes a basic edition afterwards. I think the basic edition will still allow you to do the debugging. I'm going to try it out myself.

You can also try these iOS apps too, you can find them in the iTunes App store. They give you a built in developer tools feature (right on iOS no remote debug) that mobile Safari doesn't offer.

MIH Tool - basic edition
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mihtool/id584739126?ls=1&mt=8

HTTPWatch Basic
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/httpwatch-basic-http-sniffer/id658886056?mt=8

I gave them a try and they're at least better than the mobile Safari you get on iOS, unless one needs to target full mobile Safari compatibility. I'm guessing the pro/paid editions of those apps give you more/better features.

Answer (score 1):

iOS Debugging with Safari is a featuere of the new Safari. As Safari for Windows is a outdated Version of Safari, debugging is not Implemented.

So debugging with Safari is only possible on a mac!

min requirements are: OS X 10.8 iOS 6

More Infos:

[Safari Remote Debugging on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598415/safari-remote-debugging-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Since that Question was asked i found another neat way to debug stuff on a not accessible Platform:

http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/

It works like this:

1. You add the weinre.js to your project
2. You set up weinre on your main platform (pc)
3. Starting your project results in sending the Debug Information from your project to your Platform

It's not that easy to run and understand, but once it works its pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your phone to allow remote webview inspection?

http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: Yep, it simply doesn't work in windows I guess. I had to get my hands on a Mac in order to test it.

Comment: You may want to restart safari and/or your iPhone or the browser in your iPhone. Things sometimes just go wrong...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [Weinre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32314979/3111787), you can try Vanamco's [Ghostlab](https://www.vanamco.com/ghostlab/) as well, it supports JS console and parallel testing on multiple device.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.