# How to do remote debugging with Browser-sync?

Tags: remote-debugging, browser-sync

I have installed browser sync with npm. On their website, they have mentioned that it also allows remote debugging. But they have not mentioned that how to do remote debugging.
I have used below command to run mysite on browser-sync.
browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8080/mysite

how can I remote debug that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though this was quite a tricky process in versions before Browser-sync 2.0, but with Browser-sync 2.0 you now have a brand new Web UI, which makes this process a whole lot easier.

Firstly you need to update Browser-sync to it's latest version

> npm install -g browser-sync@latest

Then run any command like you would.
eg:

> browser-sync start --proxy "myproject.dev" --files "css/*.css"

To open this Web UI open

> http://localhost:3001

Below are links to articles that talk about Remote Debuggging in Browser-Sync:

- http://www.wearejh.com/news/browsersync-2-0/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/improve-workflow-browsersync-2-0/

[image: Browser-sync]

Comment: Was this removed in more recent versions, or is there some additional setup required?  The "Remote Debugger (weinre)" option doesn't show up for me (using 2.18.5 here).

Comment: @candu it does show to me, but my Android device doesn't appear on the listing. ='(

Comment: removed at present https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1413#issuecomment-352859886