# Prevent iOS 6 from Caching Ajax POST Requests

Tags: ajax, caching, cordova, safari, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results)

I have a hybrid application using `PhoneGap` that runs fine on Android and iOS. But when I started testing in iOS 6 I noticed that I am not getting server data for most of my ajax calls - instead I was getting the cached data from previous ajax calls.

So far I have tried the following options to disable cache -

1. Include a timestamp as query string parameter
2. `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`
3. Inside the ajax call `no-cache = true`
4. `$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
       options.data =
           jQuery.param($.extend(originalOptions.data||{}, { timeStamp: new
           Date().getTime() })); });`

But none of these seems to be working. I am invoke Java action classes from my ajax calls - will it have something to do with the reason why the methods listed above are failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this thread

[Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results)

You could disable the caching on webserver level and by using timestamps in the URL.

Answer (score 5):

How to fix it: There are various methods to prevent caching of requests. The recommended method is adding a no-cache header.

This is how it is done.

**jQuery**:

Check for iOS 6.0 and set Ajax header like this.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

**ZeptoJS** :

Check for iOS 6.0 and set Ajax header like this.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
headers : { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
url : ,
data:,
dataType : 'json',
success : function(responseText) {…}
```

Server side

**Java** :

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
```

Make sure to add this at the top the page before any data is sent to the client.

**.NET**

```
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Or

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

**PHP**

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
```