# iOS downloaded JSON get's cached, how to prevent?

Tags: ios, caching, cordova

I've created an app (for iOS 6) that downloads a json file on startup. This happens when the app starts so it runs the latest content.

Somehow the JSON get's cached and the app uses the old, cached, version above the freshly downloaded one.

When I delete cache.db from the Library/Caches// (in the simulator) it uses the fresh JSON file. So I'd like to know how to prevent the JSON being saved in this cache.db or how to delete or empty it?

I've been looking for ages.

Thanks

Btw, the app is made with phonegap.

Comment: Append a dummy random-number parameter to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Phonegap but in iOS you can implement the method `- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse` and return nil if you don't want your downloaded data to be cached (if you're using `NSURLConnection` to download).

Comment: Except that that doesn't work if a gateway somewhere is doing the caching.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12796318/1276002) SO question, 
and the simple idea here is to disable the caching on webserver level and by using timestamps in the URL.