# phonegap iPhone app caching old data

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, cordova

Phonegap 2.1
iOS 6
jQuery 1.7.2
JQMobile 1.1.1

I have a phonegap app that seems to be caching old data from ajax responses if I don't use the app for a few days.  I have to reinstall the app to clear it.  I found a fix for the app itself but that would require re-publishing.  It connects to a .NET WCF REST service, is there a way to just turn off caching on that end?  I don't have outputCache in the webconfig at all so it may be on by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796318/prevent-ios-6-from-caching-ajax-post-requests

Comment: I'm going to try the ajax headers, hopefully that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also append a random number as a query parameter to your AJAX request URL to force the cache to update i.e. `https://example.com/request.asp?timestamp=02347892378`.

Comment: Ajax headers worked fine so far.  I'll mark this as an answer also though.