# phonegap gwt mobile app runs only the first time on iOS6

Tags: iphone, gwt, cordova, ios6

I have a mobile app that's developed in mgwt and gwt-phonegap 1.8

It uses GWT-RPC, It works really well in iOS5 and all versions of Android.

In iOS6 the application works well only the first time.
Then if I start it again it appears that has cached the state from the previous session. (screens, values)
I have no mechanism to do that, and what's more the screens are dynamically created.
In addition, I have not used the mgwt linker that enables the application to run offline.

Anyone has an idea, what's causing this or how to deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the iOS6 webcontrol is caching the POST requests:

[Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results)