# jQuery Ajax Phonegap IOS cache

Tags: ios, jquery, caching, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results)

I have the problem that i think cache:false in $.ajax dont work.

Example
URL: update.php return: 1
But i should return: 0

Rename update.php to update2.php
Return: 0

```
url:    '/update.php',
cache:  false,
type:   "POST",
data:   {checkPost: $("#kvittens").val()},  
crossDomain:    true,
```

The update.php code

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    echo(0);
?>
```

Comment: Most likely this is your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results