# Is the iOS 6 caching $.ajax results issue resolved in iOS 6.0.1?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, safari, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results)

Does anyone know if the now infamous [iOS 6 caching $.ajax results issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results) resolved in iOS 6.0.1?

Comment: This question won't be useful for very long, so I'm voting to close for too localized.

Comment: Could someone kindly point me in the direction of the duplicate questions?