# ajax form submit not working on iPhone Safari

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax, forms, safari

I have created a form allowing the user to select a photo.  Upon selection, the form is submitted automatically via ajax (as opposed to having a standard submit button).  It works fine in all browsers, but it does not work on the mobile version of safari.

My HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="php/upload.php" method="post">
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" id="uploadPhotoButton"/>
</form>
```

My javascript:

```
$(':file').change(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/upload.php',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        success: uploadComplete,
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

On iPhone Safari, the change handler function is called fine, but the ajax call fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, it turns out that the call to ajax is working fine, but for some reason the php script it calls is failing only on iPhone Safari when tries to upload the file:  

    `$target_path = "../uploads/";  

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);   

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {  
  
    } else{  
    
    }`  

move_uploaded_file is returning false.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that in iOS6, safari caches post calls...  The solution is here: [Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results)