# Jquery Ajax file upload not working on Iphone

Tags: java, php, jquery, iphone, ajax

Whenever I try to upload on an iPhone device, it calls the success callback but the file doesn't get uploaded. The code actually works on windows, android and iPhone 5 but doesn't work on other higher iPhone versions.
I know this question has already been asked but the answers didn't solve my problem.

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['data']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//$_FILES['upl']['name']
$source = 'uploads/' . 'image.' . $extension;
$target = 'uploads/' . 'image.jpg';
if (file_exists($target)) {
    unlink($target);
}
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['data']['tmp_name'], $source)) {
    $status = ['status' => "success", 'filename' => base_url() . '/' . $target];
```

Javascript

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   type: 'POST',
   headers: {
     "cache-control": "no-cache"
   },
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false
});
$.ajax({
    url: document.location.href+"/upload.php?timestamp=" + (new Date).getTime(),
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    error: error,
    success: success
});
```

Comment: Could you link to the questions that you thought were similar to the one you have?

Comment: Here's a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709939/ajax-form-submit-not-working-on-iphone-safari?rq=1