# IOS 6 Caching Everything except Cache Manifest. Updated files never being requested from web server

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile, cache-manifest

Our web app is being cached so aggressively in ios 6 app mode that the only file being requested from the web server every time is the cache manifest. We have changed a bunch of scripts and html, but the app never requests the new files. How can I fix this if nothing is requested from the web server? Is there a way that I can fix this in the cache manifest? Bear in mind that we are only using the cache manifest to cache images, fonts, etc and not the js itself. Any help would be much appreciated, I'm stumped!

Edit 1:

The content of the cache manifest has changed. I even put a guid in the cache manifest each time just to ensure that it is different. I've run charles and see that the page keeps requesting the manifest repeatedly, with 200 respone.. Seems to be something really weird going on with the ios 6 native app mode wrapper.

Comment: Did you change the manifest file itself (some version number inside). If not, it might be that nothing is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You get all the infos you need on this website: http://appcachefacts.info/

If you want to refresh the cached files, you have to change the content of appcache.manifest.

Comment: As I said, we don't reference the javascript in the cachemanifest. Anyhow, whether I change the cache-manifest or not, it just keeps getting requested...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link helps: [Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results).

iOS6.0 is caching pretty much everything I assume... In our app, it was Ajax Post being cached and breaking the application. I hope it's fixed with setting cache:false on Ajax requests, but I'm not really sure. Otherwise I will add a random string to all AJAX requests.

Supposedly post-chaching is fixed in iOS6.1 beta, hopefully for web-app mode, too.

Comment: nope, this isn't an ajax request, it is the initial request for the web page. As the web page is cached, I can't do anything with it! At least with ajax requests I can append a timestamp to the path.