# How long will Safari cache results from AJAX POST requests in iOS 6.0/6.0.1?

Tags: ajax, caching, safari, ios6

I have recently come face-to-face with the issue of Safari caching the results of AJAX POST requests in iOS 6.0 and 6.0.1, as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results).

I have implemented a workaround so that the app will now add a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header to all responses of POST requests. The application, an ASP.NET web app, was previously returning a value of `private` for the `Cache-Control` header, which I suppose is the default (we were not explicitly setting it anywhere). No timespan was included.

While the workaround is serving us well for end users that are submitting a request to a particular URL for the first time, users that already have cached data could still be impacted. In the case where no specific timespan for caching is given to Safari, how long will it cache POST request data before it expires?

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about this and you want to clear the cached requests, you can always change the POST request by adding some new hidden field with some value you don't even care about.  Since this is a new request, the browser should not rely on it's cached response.

Comment: I have considered this option. The only problem is that there are hundreds of web service calls done via an HTTP POST throughout this particular app. If the app had been built with a library like jQuery, adding an extra hidden field to any outgoing POST request would be cake, but in this case ASP.NET AJAX is being used, and I'm not sure if any kind of pre-request filter can be created in order to add a hidden field to any outgoing POST request. I will look in to it further though.