# Local storage does not clean properly on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstorage

This will make me crazy. This happens on iphone 4S Safari(IOS 6) but **not** on any desktop browser.

Everytime before I make a new request I flush the jStorage, on Alert test1 everything is null as I expect. But the second alert Test2 shows an **older data** from storage but **not** the "**data**" received and setted in **success function**.

How is this possible?

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$.jStorage.flush();
    localStorage.clear();
alert("Test1 "+$.jStorage.get('token')+"tu:"+$.jStorage.get('user'));

$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rs/user/token",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function (xhr){

        },
        success: function (data){
            $.jStorage.set('token', data);
            $.jStorage.set('user',username);             
            changemenu('menu.html');
            alert("Test2 "+$.jStorage.get('token')+"tu:"+$.jStorage.get('user'));
        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried without using the jquery plugin? Since its very easy to use even without a plugin, i suggest you try

Comment: You should try setting up a simple replication of your problem. The solution will most likely come up, and be easier to answer.

Comment: @Spring I meant: write the simplest code possible that replicates the behavior.

Comment: might be the browser ignores the cache flag...

Comment: Are you sure that localstorage is supported by the browser that you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it has nothing todo with localstorage, **STUPID** IOS 6 safari caches all POST requests, so it secretly returns same token on every request..this is the dumbest thing I've seen for long time!

http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/09/developers-claim-safari-in-ios-6-breaks-web-apps-with-aggressive-caching/

[Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results)