# Allow access to PHP file only through ajax on local server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security

I have a website that needs to increment values in a database based upon user interaction. When users click a button a php script is called that increments the value. I'd like to protect this script from being accessed by outside scripts. Currently a user could write their own web page with a javascript function that hits the same php file repeatedly to blow up the value in the database.

Here's my jquery code that does the incrementing:

```
jQuery(function(){
$('.votebtn').click(function(e){
    var mynum = $(this).attr('id').substring(0,5);
    $.ajax({
            url:"countvote.php",
            type:"GET",
            data: { 
                thenum:mynum
            },
            cache: false,
            success:function(data) {
                alert('Success!');
                }
            }
        });
});
});
```

How would I go about making it so that only a call from ajax/jquery on the local server can access 'countvote.php'? If that's not the correct way to go about it, I'm open to any suggestion that will prevent my php script from being abused by outside scripts.

Comment: Can you restrict the sites that can access countvote.php to only those on your domain?

Comment: @user829323 This is trivial to forge outside of the browser with `wget`

Answer (score 42):

The solution needs two steps.

Firstly the ajax file must allow access only in ajax request with this code.

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&      strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if(!IS_AJAX) {die('Restricted access');}
```

Secondly the ajax file has access in the name of file that call it with command $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. 
So you can restrict access only in the host server.

```
$pos = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],getenv('HTTP_HOST'));
if($pos===false)
  die('Restricted access');
```

Maybe the code can work only with the second part

Comment: This doesn't work. Anyone can send an X-Requested-With and Referer header with whatever values they like.

Comment: @Quentin, so what is your solution to solve the requirements? A secret given on the initalsite?

Comment: @mr.void — There isn't a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` equals `xmlhttprequest`, but it's not a reliable method to determine whether a request is an AJAX request or not, there is always a way to get around this. But it protects you from random hits like wrongly entered urls, crawlers etc.

Answer (score 2):

Theres not really a 100% method of doing so. AJAX requests are always going to come from a client. Use POST requests instead of GET and that will help deter any issues but not completely stop them and in your php, just drop all get requests.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't an option. I discovered the hard way that iOS 6 caches POST request results from JQuery/AJAX. So on mobile devices the response info is inaccurate.

Comment: Check this answer to fix that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think you need JQuery 1.5 or higher to use the header control. Unfortunately I hamstrung into using 1.3 which doesn't support this. It's part of a CMS that I don't have the ability to update currently. Thanks though.

Comment: Ugh, sucks dude. Sorry I couldn't help. Hope you find your solution!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work, but whats about settings an API key on eg. index.php into a `$_SESSION` variable, afaik this cannot be visible to the user, unless you do it manually, then in the restricted php file, check the `$_SESSION['VOTEAPIKEY']` or whatever

Comment: Good idea, this is much harder to spoof than the other answers.