# In Safari, why is the $_POST array empty after jQuery AJAX call?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, safari

**In Safari only**, why is the `$_POST` array empty when posting using a jQuery AJAX call?

IE, Firefox and Chrome all output correctly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function()
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "target.php",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: ({
                        'param1': 'param1'
                    }),
                    success: function()
                    {
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The file `target.php` contains the following code:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

and outputs the following:

```
Array
(
)
```

Comment: Why is `data` an object in brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues found the answer:

http://forums.iis.net/post/1999417.aspx

Hope this helps other people...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `(` and `)` in `data`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be related to iOS 6 caching certain post requests.  Have a look at this post: [ios caching post request responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results).

You could test this by checking if you're using no Cache-Control headers or "Cache-Control: max-age=0" and removing them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are setting the datatype to xml I guess this should be html since you're not getting xml as responce. see: http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

quote : "Why is data an object in brackets?"

also use async : true in your request if Mark roper is correct.

```
 $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "target.php",
                async :true,
                dataType: "html",
                data: {
                    'param1': 'param1'
                },
                success: function(data) {
            alert(String(data));
            }
            });
        });
```

Just changed the success to :
 success: function(data) {alert(String(data));}
EDIT: on http://peervantienen.com/Stackoverflow/in-safari-why-is-the-post-array-empty-after-jquery-ajax-call/ it gave me the same results in all browsers.

Comment: I updated the code to the above, and the post array is still empty :(

Comment: I'll try to recreate it in a few hours from now.

Comment: Hi, the solution in this link seems to work in all browsers. can you take a look? http://www.peervantienen.com/Stackoverflow/in-safari-why-is-the-post-array-empty-after-jquery-ajax-call/ . (I'm a bit surprised how php returns the array btw)