# jquery ajax cache:false not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some information which I can edit and then update, and then I get the updated content via ajax which works fine, but the image gets cached and does not change (the image has the same name, and if a new image is uploaded it literally overwrites the previous one).

If i THEN refresh the page, I see the new image, and if I then edit and update the image from then on, it works good, but the FIRST time is always the problem. I always have to do manual page refresh after updating the content.

My ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: vkrwps_admin.ajax_url,
    data: {
        action: 'EDIT_PROD',
        sv: sv,
        preload: vkrwps_admin.preloader
    },
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('div.mule').html(u);
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('div.mule').html(response);
        // call chosen on select
        $('select').chosen({
            // placeholder_text: "Choose a product..."
            'disable_search': true
        });
        // $('select.dropsearch').val(4).trigger('change');
    },
    complete: function() {
        // $('select.dropsearch').one().val(cf).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

I also tried putting the following on top of the script, but didn't help:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the response of the ajax all that needs cache busting, it's the image, and it's updated on the server, but you're still loading the same URL, so it doesn't update on the clientside.

Try adding a random querystring to the images to load the images again, in the ajax success function do

```
       success: function(response){
            var r = (new Date()).getTime();

            $('div.mule').html(response).find('img').prop('src', function(_, src) {
                 return src + '?v=' + r;
            });

            $('select').chosen({
                // placeholder_text: "Choose a product..."
                'disable_search': true
            }); 
            // $('select.dropsearch').val(4).trigger('change');
        },
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you have the underscore `_` as the first argument of the `prop` callback function?

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm - To get to the second argument, we need to actually have the first argument, which is an index, and it's not needed in the code, so I tend to just use the underscore to show that it's not in use, but something has to be typed there, so why not an underscore. Any character or variable name would do as well, it's just a habit.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
});
```

You can find more solution in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results/12542888).