# Auto refresh UIwebview issue in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I have developed an app in which I load the data into webView. My webpage refresh in every 5 seconds through an ajax call. It is working fine in android. Rendering of page in android is very fast. It doesn't seem that url is reloaded in android but in iOS when page refreshing is very slow. Can anybody please tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using WKWebView instead of UIWebView?

Comment: No i am using uiwebview.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer to [Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results) link.

I think it will solve your problem if you do not allow cache data to load while refreshing UIWebView

Comment: I don't want to use timer my webpage is already reloading through ajax.Please tell the way out

Comment: @iAnurag : You have used `repeats:NO`. If we want timer to fire after every 5 sec, we should use `repeats:YES`.

Comment: How to avoid this issue please tell?